# How to split string one by one in C#?

Tags: c#, string, split

I was trying to make a typing program, and I wanted to split a string word by word.

For example, if the input is "Hi nice to meet you", then I want an array with "H", "i", " ", "n", "i", "c", "e", " ", "t", "o", " " ..... so on with all the blanks and punctuation.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: If I not mistaken string have method: ToCharArray()

Comment: The MSDN documents are the best source of information. Whatever happened to finding out on your own initiative on such a simple language/runtime matter? Visual Studio has that support in place so a bit more effort would be needed.

Comment: What is your definition of a word? If you want an array of char elements: Well, basically, a string is already one...

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use [`String.ToCharArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string yourText = "Hi nice to meet you";
char[] arrayOfCharacters = yourText.ToCharArray(); 
// this gives you char[] with all the characters in your string
```

Comment: Why would that be needed if you could also access a strings single chars via indexer and iterate over the string elements as if it were a char array?

Comment: @Udontknow that depends on what you want to do with it - if you only want to access a specific character at known position then indexer is the way to go, but if you want to do something that only character array supports, then you can use this method to convert to `char[]`. It is hard to tell without knowing the context